# Как занести цикл Do While в переменную?

Tags: php, циклы

Добрый день.

Есть цикл

```
do
{
    echo "<option value='$myrow19[id]'>$myrow19[estnet]</option>";

}
while($myrow19 = mysql_fetch_array($result19));
```

Как можно весь цикл занести в переменную, чтобы можно было этот цикл с помощью этой переменной вставить в любое место в коде?

Comment: Можно просто потом функцию вызвать

Comment: выбрось курсы попова!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, имеется в виду, заранее подготовить эту тучу option'ов и затем эхом её вставить где-то, как-то?

```
$options = '';
do {
    $options .= sprintf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
        $myrow19[id],
        $myrow19[estnet]
    );
} while( $myrow19 = mysql_fetch_array( $result19));
```

И потом где-то в коде:

```
echo $options;
```

Comment: Воооооо вот это подошло спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте занести цикл в функцию, а потом функцию занесите в переменную:

```
function cikl(){ Здесь цикл }
```

Answer (score 0):

В переменную? Это что-то новое )) Вы можете записать этот цикл в функцию и вызывать её в том месте, где это надо:

```
function myCycle($result19) {
    do {
        echo "<option value='$myrow19[id]'>$myrow19[estnet]</option>";
    } while($myrow19 = mysql_fetch_array($result19));

}

// И вызов функции
myCycle($result19);
```

В функцию надо будет передавать параметр $result19

Comment: Почему то одна строчка при выводе пропадает